# Postgresql 9: substring with regex to get string between string and pipe

Tags: regex, string, postgresql

I need to create a query using the `SUBSTRING` function in Postgresql 9.x to extract a substring between a string and first pipe occurrence.

My source string is something like this:

```
THIS IS MY EXAMPLE|OTHER EXAMPLE|HELLO: Kevin|OTHER EXAMPLE|OTHER EXAMPLE
```

So I created this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(myField from 'HELLO: (.*)\|') AS test FROM myTable
```

to get the word `Kevin` between the string `'HELLO: '` and the first occurrence of character pipe, but it doesn't work as intended because it returns `Kevin|OTHER EXAMPLE|OTHER EXAMPLE`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try using `HELLO: ([^|]+)`, like `SELECT SUBSTRING(myField from 'HELLO: ([^|]+)') AS test FROM myTable`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Your pattern is almost right, you just need to understand, that `*` is [greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). You can use its non-greedy (lazy) counterpart: `*?`, like `'HELLO: (.*?)\|'` (which works in PostgreSQL too). (And of course the posted answer is right too, you can get around greediness with altering the pattern logic too.)

Comment: Did my suggestion work in the end? Please let know if you need more help with this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a negated character class in order not to "overflow" to the next `|`-separated parts:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(myField from 'HELLO: ([^|]+)') AS test FROM myTable
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ1rJ9/1) of how this regex works. The `[^|]+` pattern matches *one or more characters other than a literal pipe*.